# HTML input only allow numbers and letters and @

Tags: php, html, input

I've got a question and I hope someone of you have a solution for this.
Well I have this code:

```
<input type="text" id="username"  placeholder="Email/Username"
       class="Username placeholder NoPlaceholder text"
       title="Email/Username" name="usern" value=""
       required="required" tabindex="1" maxlength="30"/>
```

I would like to limit this input field to only allow a full email address.
So to disallow other symbols like: `!#$%^&*()_+{}|:">?<`

Input pattern won't work as someone can just delete that by inspecting element.

If someone has a tip or idea comment below!

Comment: I'm sure you could just use a regex to validate it, either on the server or in the browser with JavaScript. BTW, some of those characters **are** allowed in email addresses, and users will be frustrated if they cannot enter their fully valid email ! Would also be good to clarify your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650617/html-form-field-how-to-require-an-input-format

Answer (score 1):

just use HTML5 field validator:

```
<form>
<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This will force the user to enter a text string, which makes sense for an email address..

Success!

Comment: But the thing is, I have a second input bar where other information is filled in, they can just put javascript in there and it will be posted to my sql db which is not that nice :s

Comment: You should be validating the data server-side as well. Information sent by the client application can be faked easily regardless of any validations made with javascript or the HTML5 validation elements.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a text type, use HTML5's email type:

```
<input type="email" name="email">
```

Comment: But the thing is, I have a second input bar where other information is filled in, they can just put javascript in there and it will be posted to my sql db which is not that nice :s

Comment: You need to post your code and markup to your question. The email type will not validate JavaScript so you will have to show us what you mean.