# Check if string is valid SSN as its being typed using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to do a validate check to see if the SSN entered into a textbox follows this specific format: `XXX-XX-XXXX` as its being typed

I tried doing a function that just auto formats like this...

```
function ssnCheck() {
    var val = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    var newVal = '';
    if(val.length > 4) {
        this.value = val;
    }
    if((val.length > 3) && (val.length < 6)) {
        newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
        val = val.substr(3);
    }
    if (val.length > 5) {
        newVal += val.substr(0, 3) + '-';
        newVal += val.substr(3, 2) + '-';
        val = val.substr(5);
    }

    newVal += val;
    this.value = newVal;
}
```

But it would bug out sometimes and not fully work especially on Mobile devices.   I tried the solutions below, but they aren't working.  The way I'm applying the above is by doing this..

```
document.getElementById("ssn").addEventListener('keyup',ssnCheck,false);
```

Any help on getting it to work so it auto formats as its being typed, or a better solution to this issue since it HAS to show in the XXX-XX-XXXX format when they are done typing in the box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSN Regex for 123-45-6789 OR XXX-XX-XXXX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087468/ssn-regex-for-123-45-6789-or-xxx-xx-xxxx)

Comment: Just scan for 9 digits, and don't accept any other characters. Formatting is *your* responsibility.

Comment: @PM77-1 I don't want a simple reg-ex I want it to happen as they are typing

Comment: So you cannot just use a `pattern` attribute (or its poly-fill) like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21650828/2055998)?

Answer (score 0):

try this regax:

```
^\d{3}(?:[-]\d{2})(?:[-]\d{4})?$
```

- ^ = Start of the string.
- (?:…) = Grouping
- \d{3} = Match 3 digits
- \d{2} = Match 2 digits
- \d{4} = Match 4 digits
- [-] = Match a hyphen
- $ = End of the string